# Binary operator "<=" can't be applied to operands of type Bool and Int

Tags: swift, swift3

```
if 1 <= A[i] <= 100 || 1 <= B[i] <= 100
```

for the above line I get these two error.
1. Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'Comparision Precendence'
2. Binary operator "<=" can not be applied to type `BOOL` and `Int`.

Comment: You need to use the range pattern operator `1...100 ~= a[i]`

Answer (score 3):

try `if (1 <= A[i] && A[i] <= 100) || (1 <= B[i] && B[i] <= 100)`

Answer (score 3):

Joe's answer and Leo's comment would both work.  My preference would be Leo's approach (using `1...100 ~= A[i]`), but whatever floats your boat.

That said, let me explain WHY what you did is giving you an error.  Without any parenthesis to break it up, it evaluates that going left to right.  So if first checks "is 1 <= A[i]?", and that results in a boolean answer.  It then tries to ask "is true <= 100?", which makes no sense.